# How to loop through csv numeric data as individual rows in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with one excel type column of numeric data in many excel type rows, but I don't understand how to parse through each "row".
Example: I don't know how to add the first row value of -0.164 to the second row value of -0.1640.

What I am eventually needing to do is loop through this data and get the average value for the first 10 rows, have if - then statements based on that value. Then get the average value for the next 10 rows and repeat until I'm at the end of the data.

[image]

Here is code I used with commented out lines of me trying to understand how to add one row to another

```
import csv
with open('grayramp_line28_NoHblank.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            print(row)
        #value = float(row[0]) + float(row[1])
        #print(row[0])
        #print(row[1])
        #print(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal here is to loop over the file, while updating a variable to keep track of the running sum and output an average. You've already figured out the loop part.

The problem with `float(row[0]) + float(row[1])` is that the row variable represents all of the column values within a specific row. So this means that it adds the first column to the second column, and then that becomes the value of the variable `value`. That's not really what was intended.

What you might do, in order to do an average of the whole file, is this:

```py
import csv
with open('grayramp_line28_NoHblank.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sum_ = 0
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        sum_ += float(row[0])
        count += 1
    print("Average:", sum_ / count)
```

But you don't really want an average of all rows, you want an average for each group of ten rows. So you need an if inside the loop, which checks if you've collected enough values:

```py
import csv
with open('grayramp_line28_NoHblank.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sum_ = 0
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        sum_ += float(row[0])
        count += 1
        if count >= 10:
            print("Average:", sum_ / count)
            # reset average
            sum_ = 0
            count = 0
    # Are there any samples left over? Print an average if so
    if count > 0:
        print("Average:", sum_ / count)
```

So that will print once for every ten samples. That's useful for debugging purposes, but you probably want to put the averages in a variable, so you can do other processing steps with it.

Example:

```py
import csv
with open('grayramp_line28_NoHblank.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sum_ = 0
    count = 0
    samples = []
    for row in reader:
        sum_ += float(row[0])
        count += 1
        if count >= 10:
            samples.append(sum_ / count)
            # reset average
            sum_ = 0
            count = 0
    # Are there any samples left over? Add to list if so
    if count > 0:
        samples.append(sum_ / count)
```

This creates a list with the averaged data.